# Remove the information from the BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, blob, templavoila

There is a site: http://www.sleepsystem.ru/
Compiled with the help of a template TemplaVoilà.
In the code of the site on all pages except the main (commented on it) there is a record (about 186 string):

```
<script src = "http://savehalf.traffictools.ru/counter.js" type = "text / javascript"> </ script>
```

Because of her site is loaded more than 20 seconds. You must remove this record.

Sits this string in the database MYSQL. In the table "tx_templavoila_tmplobj" column: "templatemapping" three records in the files of the BLOB.

When editing the data files via dbForge Studio for MYSQL and removing the desired line, the site stops working with the error:

```
Template Object could not be unserialized successfully.
Are you sure you saved mapping information into Template Object with UID "4"
```

It seems that the problem is in Cyrillic characters within the data BLOB files, delete them but there is no way. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

You're directly editing serialized data, which means you're probably corrupting it. You can't just wade in and start swinging a machete. You have to preserve the serialization scaffolding as well.

e.g.

```
php > echo serialize('this is a string');
s:16:"this is a string";
```

So you've got this serialized string in the database, and you do some machete work in the DB and change it to

```
s:16:"this is an elephant";
```

which gives you :

```
php > echo unserialize('s:16:"this is an elephant"');
PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 22 of 26 bytes in php shell code on line 1
```

Ooops, now it's corrupted. The proper edit would have been to change the size parameter as well:

```
s:19:"this is an elephant";
```

Whatever the serialization format is for this templating system of yours, you'll have to recreate EXACTLY what it does in order to directly modify the serialized data.

Comment: After making changes to the database template in the admin asks "Update map" for these templates. Then use the template engine - remap. Then the error disappears:

`code`Template Object could not be unserialized successfully.
Are you sure you saved mapping information into Template Object with UID "4"

But! pattern of BLOB no longer displayed on the site at all,  that is all between <body> - empty.